# ASP.NET and AJAX library - Extremely slow !

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

So, i'm new to ASP.NET and AJAX.
I am trying out the Beta library.

I setup a page and was using the Editor.
The loading of this page is well, slow.

There is nothing more than then, you can see it here

http://eski.internet.is/default.aspx but it will take a min to load.

Whats is the reason for the slow load, is it the AJAX library ?
Its about 7 mb, the .dll's. Is it downloading it everytime you load the page ?

Comment: the user woulnd't be downloading dlls - they're only used server-side. have you tried debugging? put breakpoints in your page_load(), at the beginning & end. is execution quick between the first one and last one? How about from the time the you navigate to the page until it hits the first breakpoint? how about from the time it takes after teh last breakpoint until the page renders onto the screen? I've had performance diffulties with ASP.NET AJAX before where there's lots of controls on the page, but you don't have many controls

Comment: Also check the javascript you are using.

Comment: When debugging i set breakpoint at page_load. When its over that there is a popup.

There is no source code available for the current location
Then it says that this files isnt there which is true =>
C:\AjaxBuild\Ajax\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManager.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't load the whole 7mb worth of .dlls - that's the code that generates the output.

For that site I'm getting this from YSlow:
HTTP Requests - 46
Total Weight - 304.9K

```
1   HTML/Text   121.9K

4   JavaScript File 161.7K

3   Stylesheet File 6.4K

38  Image   14.7K
```

Which isn't that much.  It did seem to take a LONG time for the host to respond, however.  What are the specs on your server and its internet connection?

In your web.config do you have debug="true"?  If so, take that out as it can cause pages to take longer as it then generates debug information.

Comment: Once the host responded, the page load was fast -- looks like it could be related to server load -- not bandwidth.

Comment: I'm on fiber and the host is good, sites that i know of are fast..
The debug is false, it doesnt seem to matter if its true or false regarding the speed..

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be hanging on any one component being served to the client. It seems to be either server load or something in your code. Can you provide the code that you are using to better help diagnose this?

Comment: yah, first thing when i get to work.. basicly i used visual studio and dragged asp.net editor, 2 textboxes and buttons to the webform..

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that website http://eski.internet.is/default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropShadowExtender ID="TextBox1_DropShadowExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </asp:DropShadowExtender>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="To Editor" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" Width="500" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="To Textbox" 
        onclick="Button2_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="161px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
        Width="600px"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok, so i found somewhere on the net that i had to install sp1 for visual studio and i did.. now i get a error msg on everything i do when its on the host..
i talked to the host and the server has also sp1..
the error msg is here..

http://eski.internet.is/web/default.aspx

Line 52:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 53:         -->
Line 54:         <authentication mode="Windows" />
Line 55:         <!--
Line 56:             The <customErrors> section enables configuration